# R - How to Remove Items in a Vector that Satisfy One of Several Conditions

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe which contains a column of names, and given the nature of my data the names repeat.  I also have a vector of a subset of those names that I need to eliminate from that dataframe.  So I want to identify the row number for each instance that the name in the dataframe matches a name in the list of names to be dropped.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do...but I can't get the code to work. Thanks!

```
a=c("tom", "bill", "sue", "jim", "tom", "amy")
b=c(12,15,7,22,45,5)

ab=data.frame(a,b)

ab

drop=which(ab$a==c("tom", "sue")) #only identifies those matching "tom"

drop

ab2=ab[-drop,]

ab2
```

Answer (score 9):

you're looking for `%in%`

```
drop=which(ab$a %in% c("tom", "sue"))
```

however, more succinctly:

```
ab[!ab$a %in% c('tom', 'sue'),]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the package sqldf.
You may perform SQL Selects on R Data Frames.